# Delete all but first 100 rows in table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was wondering if there is a way to delete everything but the first 100 rows in a a table in a mysql database. Can this be done using the phpmyadmin GUI.

Comment: @FastSnail So you can select 100 you want to KEEP and delete the rest ?

Comment: something like:  `delete from foo where id >100`

Comment: @seus sorry i misread it.i think it's hard to do in gui.but you can edit mysql query in the gui .check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292375/delete-all-rows-except-first-n-from-a-table-having-single-column

Comment: @Dragon how do i cascade deletes with all foreign keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, depending what you mean by "first 100". I'm assuming you have an auto-increment primary key column (e.g. `id`) and the "first 100" rows would be the rows that show up first when ordered by that column. If so, to find the last `id` of the first 100 rows, you'd write:

```
SELECT MAX(m.id) FROM (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 100) m
```

Now, you want to delete any rows with the `id` greater than this max, so you write:

```
DELETE FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  id > (SELECT MAX(m.id)
        FROM
          (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 100) m);
```

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b3f52/1) that's demonstrating this for 5 rows.

Comment: Thank you this helped :)

Comment: You also can do: `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 100);`

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you alternative approach. Let me know if it works for you?

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable LIMIT 100;
```

It will a create new table with first 100 records, this way you will keep backup of old table also. if you want it then keep it or delete it.

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. Also, this needn't be two separate queries. Basically, this is a good approach, but it needs some tweaking.

Comment: I think I've made it clear, It is an alternative approach which can solve the question. If required you can always add ORDER BY clause.

Comment: An ORDER BY clause is always required.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Delete from table where id > 0 and id <101

this will delete the record from 1 to 100 unless you create a loop of it..

loop will do in stored proc i guess..